# React: Creating interactive components in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

My goal is to create an input div that checks whether numeric values are provided a currency tag or not. The content-editable div should locate numeric values and preferably convert them to individual components which each can show an option tooltip for the user to assign a currency value to each value.

Here is what I am currently working on: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-4uizr

## Currently known issues:

- Using the current `react-contenteditable` component, prevents me from rendering anything but pure HTML, but if I use a normal div with attribute `contenteditable`, the caret f***s around, and overall the callbacks and UX is better using the  `react-contenteditable` component.
- Due to state changes when displaying the options section, all custom JS added to target the current selected element is gone, and can't seem to persist this in any way.

## Real world example

If you go to Facebook and start writing a new status update, and you start writing out the name of a friend, it will display a list of options and assign these to the element you are currently writing. Knowing how to do that, should make it easy to do the same for numeric values and currency values I believe.

---

Basically I am just afraid (well also hoping for...) that I am overcomplicating things here, and someone out there can tell me:

> **Dude! this is like the easiest thing ever! Just do like this!**

Comment: Facebook uses https://draftjs.org/  which you could use as well. Not saying this is your best solution - just wanted to point it out as you compared your needs to facebook's.

Comment: Even more specifically - this seems very similar to what you are looking for: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/tweet/tweet.html

Comment: @RonenRabinovici Exactly that! oh my.. Would you mind creating an answer for me to approve? And if you don't mind - please add "Dude! this is like the easiest thing ever! Just do like this!" just for the fun of it! Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use facebook's [draftjs.org](https://draftjs.org), where specifically this example seems very similar to what you are looking for: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/tweet/tweet.html